# Find value in result from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i've action which return tuple of bool and string. I want to get the first value from result (which is true or false),what is the best way to do that ?

This is the action

```
public Tuple<bool, string> Check
```

this is the ajax call which return result

```
 $.post(target, function (result) {
...
```

in the result I got this message and I want to get the value of true or false,what is the best way to do that ?

This is the message which is coming in result (the result value check via debug )

result= `"(False, Failed to remove)"`

I try to find the first char by position[2] but Im not sure that this is the right way to do that...

Comment: You should inspect in your browser. Just add a `debugger;` in the `success` function of your `$.post`. I have a hunch you'll get a JS array back. If so, you can access the values like this: `result[0]` and `result[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result seems off.
If inside your action you do `return Json(Tuple.Create(False, "Failed to remove"));` your result object should be something along these lines:

`{Item1: false, Item2: "Failed to remove"}`

In which case all you need to do is access `result.Item1` or `result.Item2`.

Either way, using Tuples is ugly, and you should probably create some kind of model for your action to return.

Comment: Thanks ,but way tuple is ugly ?instead of define new class you can use the tuple which will do the job...

Comment: It's mostly ugly because you'll get non-specific accessors. You might *know* that Item1 is supposed to be a bool, and Item2 a string, but without a descriptive name for those properties, it might be confusing to others and even to yourself if you ever review the code again.